# Digitalocean: cross droplet communication

Tags: node.js, digital-ocean, dokku

I have a scenario with two nodejs apps deployed on two Dokku droplets. One of my apps is three admin app which stores data to a mongodb database. The other app is the main application which reads data from that database.

How can I make this main app communicate to the database?

Answer (score 2):

You need to link the database to the dokku container via environment variables. You basically need to follow this methodology: http://12factor.net/

The database needs to be accessible via an IP and port combination on one of your two servers. If you need both servers to communicate with the database then you will need to make sure it is externally accessible and properly secured (for example via a VPN).

You can then set an environment variable like so:

dokku config:set  DB_URL='mongo://10.0.0.1:4192/database_name'

obviously changing the above to match your setup.

Another potentially easier way of doing the above is to use a dokku plugin which will basically automate those steps.

A list of plugins is available at: http://progrium.viewdocs.io/dokku/plugins

There is a mongo plugin which may suit your needs, I've used some of the others and they work well.